# Protractor/Jasmine e2e tests with Angular - test structure with login

Tags: jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I have the following code to run my app in the main default page (which is the login). 
The test fills out the form and clicks the submit button in order to login.

After a successful login, I'm waiting for the my app to route to the new page, and run more tests in this page.

```
it('it should login', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    // Login
    page.getUsernameInput().sendKeys('user');
    page.getPasswordInput().sendKeys('pass');
    page.getSubmitButton().click().then(() => {
      browser.driver.sleep(3000);
      // Run tests on new page of authenticated users
        page.getMainTitle().getText().then((text) => {
          expect(text).toBe('All Devices');
      });
    });
  });
```

**My question**

I don't really want to put all my tests in the same file, What's the right structure to test the login page and the rest of the pages in separated files?

The rest of the pages are based on a successful login, only authenticated users can have access to them.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. But I'm not even able to login, can't connect to my HttpServer running in docker... :(

Comment: Have a test for checking login functionality.  The rest of your tests have to login my default but dont necessarily have test anything with the login.  Just do Login in a `beforeAll` block

Answer (score 0):

We have all of our tests in a separate spec file, but due to security requirements we have to login for every test.  So we have this in all our tests

```js
beforeAll(function (done) {
        thisPage.loginIntoAppAsUser('administrator').then(() => {
            done();
        },
            (err) => {
                console.log('Error logging in'); done.fail(err);
            });
    });
```